# Retrieve the request body string sent in POST request in play framework java

Tags: java, post, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play framework in Java.
I want to retrieve the entire request body sent in a POST request to the play server. How can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look into `play.mvc.Http` class, you have some options there (depending on data format) i.e.

```
RequestBody body = request().body();
MultipartFormData formData = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
Map<String, String[]> params = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
String bodyText = request().body().asText();
```

You can test `request().body().asText()` i.e. using cUrl from commandline:

```
curl  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d  'Hello world !' http://domain.com/your-post-action
```

... or using some tool, like browser plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Comment: I want to get the raw body string without converting it to any java specific data structures. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should look into mentioned class :P `String bodyText = request().body().asText();`

Comment: I have tried String bodyText = request().body().asText(); . It returns null :)

Comment: Aparently your post contains i.e. form instead of plain text, try to perform call to the action - ie using Play's WS API or curl to see it works ;)

Answer (score 13):

With Play Framework 2.3 it is possible to get raw json text even is Content-Type header is application/json

```scala
def postMethod = Action(parse.tolerantText) { request =>
    val txt = request.body
}
```

Comment: Probably that would help then:
https://www.ricardclau.com/2015/06/access-to-the-raw-request-body-in-play-framework/

Answer (score 4):

If you call the following code on a request;

```
String bodyText = request().body().asText();
```

bodyText will be null if the Content-Type header is application/json

There isn't a way using the provided controller APIs to just get JSON text if the Content-Type header is application/json without first converting to a JsonNode

So the best way to do this if the application/json is your Content-Type header is

```
String bodyText = request().body().asJSON().toString();
```

This is a fail on play framework's part, because they should just have a method to get the request body as a String no matter what the Content-Type header is.

Answer (score 0):

It will give request JSON body as string. I tested it on play 2.6.x
`val body = request.body.asJson.get.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
request.body().asBytes().utf8String()
```